# Handling errors as a Future[Result] in ReactiveMongo 16.6

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

How can I output mongoDB errors in a `Result` with ReactiveMongo (16.6)? I've spent virtually the whole day looking through samples but have not been able to achieve this as of yet. The error section of the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html) returns a `Future[Unit]` rather than a `Future[Result]`. And every other example/sample that I can find either is outdated or does not do this; [example_1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/reactivemongo/alvaro$20naranjo/reactivemongo/FYUm9x8AMVo/LKyK01e9VEMJ), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146195/handling-errors-in-reactivemongo)

Here is what I would like to do:

```
  def updateById(collName: String, id: BSONObjectID) = authAction.async(parse.json) { implicit request: Request[JsValue] =>

    val oWriteJso = request.body.asOpt[JsObject]
    lazy val qJso = Json.obj("_id" -> id)

    val res = oWriteJso.map(
      wJso => mongoRepo.update(collName)(qJso, wJso)().recoverWith {
        case WriteResult.Code(11000) => Future.successful(BadRequest("it went bad"))
        case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("also bad"))
      }
    )

    res

  }
```

Of course with the function signature as `recoverWith[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U]` this code above will return an error as it needs to return a `Future[WriteResult]`. But how then would I be able to put any error messages, codes, etc (from `mongoDB`) into a `Result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html) indicates how to recover a `Future[WriteResult]`:

```
.recover {
  case WriteResult.Code(11000) =>
    // if the result is defined with the error code 11000 (duplicate error)
    println("Match the code 11000")

  case WriteResult.Message("Must match this exact message") =>
    println("Match the error message")

  // ...
}
```

Thanks to [`Future` combinators](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) (not specific to ReactiveMongo), it can be used whatever is the type of the successful value to be lifted inside the `Future`.

```
def foo[T](future: Future[WriteResult], recoveredValue: => T)(success: WriteResult => T): Future[T] = future.map(success).recover {
  case WriteResult.Code(11000) =>
    // if the result is defined with the error code 11000 (duplicate error)
    recoveredValue

  case WriteResult.Message("Must match this exact message") =>
    recoveredValue

}
```

Comment: Just before you posted; I figured out that `WriteResult` values can be called even after the type is no longer `WriteResult` so this is so useful! But I thought that I saw that this wasn't recommended in a Google Group Chat somewhere - and this seemed to be you posting this. Anyway thank-you!